# ATI Graphics Card driver creates crashlog -- where to submit?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, crash, event-log

There's now an ACEEventLog entry in windows event logger.  I was wondering where I should send these so they get fixed in the next release...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this.

> In an effort to help catch potential issues, I would kindly ask everyone to report ALL issues you're experiencing via the [Catalyst Crew Feedback Program](http://www.amd.com/us/CatalystCrewSurvey). This program was implemented to help catch potential issues with newly released drivers so that we can quickly report back to software engineering. This is the only official mechanism for AMD/ATI to track driver issues.

Comment: After trying to fill out the form, realized that I am running FirePro hardware.  That form is for Radeon stuff.  I'll fill it out and see what happens.  Thanks!